# how to add a tableRow in a tableRow?

Tags: android, tablelayout

i want to make a table like that:
[image]

i have tried something like that but is not working...

```
        <TableRow>


            <TextView
            android:textColor="#fed570"

                android:text="days"
               android:padding="3dip"  
               android:textStyle="bold"/>



    <TextView>

              <TableRow>

            <TextView
            android:textColor="#fed570"

                android:text="1"
               android:padding="3dip"  
               android:textStyle="bold"/>
            <TextView
            android:textColor="#fed570"

                android:text="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="3dip"   android:textStyle="bold"/>


//..more days
             </TableRow>

    </TextView>
        </TableRow>

</TextView>
    </TableRow>
```

Is that possible to be created?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't need everything to be a TableRow, you can do the days as a simple TextView in the TableLayout. Since rows are built of columns putting all of the numbers into one row is what you will want, The letters "A, B, C" can be the actual rows to hold your incoming data. Something more like..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffffff">
    <TextView
        android:textColor="#fed570"
        android:text="days"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:gravity="center"/>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#fed570"
            android:text="Type"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>  
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#fed570"
            android:text="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#fed570"
            android:text="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#fed570"
            android:text="3"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#fed570"
            android:text="4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#fed570"
            android:text="5"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#fed570"
            android:text="6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#fed570"
            android:text="7"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>                          
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#fed570"
            android:text="A"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#fed570"
            android:text="B"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#fed570"
            android:text="C"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </TableRow>     
</TableLayout>
```